# Extracting elements from XML records using Spark / Scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to extract elements from XML records where each xml file has many XML records. Below is the modified code and sample xmls that I'm using.

I'm expecting an array of Strings where each element of the array is `"user:id"` but the result is `":"`. I was expecting `XML.loadString` to parse each file and the result would be separate XML records. Meaning if I take the two sample files as example I would end up with 4 XML records. As it is, it's two.

After adding a `println(d)` after getting `next` what I get is the entire string that represents the file which is likely why the `getId` and `getUser` functions are not returning anything.

Am I handling the load incorrectly?

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.xml._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Details {

    def getDetails(xmlstring: String): Iterator[Node] = {
        val nodes = XML.loadString(xmlstring)
        nodes.toIterator
    }

    def getId(detail: Node): String = {
        (detail \ "id").text
    }

    def getUser(detail: Node): String = {
        (detail \ "user").text
    }

    def getDetailList(details: Iterator[Node]): Array[String] = {
        var list = ArrayBuffer[String]()
        while (details.hasNext) {
            val d = details.next
            val user = getUser(d)
            val id = getId(d)
            val formattedText = user + ":" + id
            list += formattedText
        }
        list.toArray
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Details")
        val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)

        val lines = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///path/to/files/")
        val xmlStrings = lines.map(line => line._2)
        val detailsRecords = xmlStrings.map(getDetails)
        val detailsList = detailsRecords.map(getDetailList)

        spark.stop()
    }
}
```

And two sample files...

`test.xml`

```
<details>
  <detail>
    <user>Dan</user>
    <id>5555</id>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <user>Mike</user>
    <id>6666</id>
  </detail>
</details>
```

`test2.xml`

```
<details>
  <detail>
    <user>John</user>
    <id>1234</id>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <user>Joe</user>
    <id>5678</id>
  </detail>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [XML for Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml).

With this library you can read **all** your xml files like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read
   .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
   .option("rowTag", "detail")
   .load("/home/path-with-xml-files")
```

This generates a DataFrame with schema:

```
+----+----+
|  id|user|
+----+----+
|5555| Dan|
|6666|Mike|
|1234|John|
|5678| Joe|
+----+----+
```

Then get an array from  this DF:

```
val id_users_array = df.collect
```

This array has the type:

```
id_users_array: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([5555,Dan], [6666,Mike], [1234,John], [5678,Joe])
```

If you want to print only the ids:

```
id_users_array.map(r => r.get(0)).foreach(println)
```

outputs:

```
5555
6666
1234
5678
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 4 months late but I think I got just the answer for you.

The problem lies in the `getDetails()` function. You have to tell Scala what is defined as a "node", which is `<detail>` in this case. So just modify your code as below:

```
  def getDetails(xmlstring: String): Iterator[Node] = {
    val nodes = XML.loadString(xmlstring) \\ "detail"
    nodes.toIterator
  }
```

Appending `\\ "detail"` at the end of `XML.loadString()` is all you need to get the code working as you expect.

Cheers,